# Convert float to DateTime in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have the Oracle table with the column that stores date and time in float representation. It looks like this:

```
40610.389837963 -> should be decoded to 5/11/2011 16:06

40676.2641666667 -> should be decoded to 5/13/2011 6:20
```

I know the encoded value and decoded value, but I don't know how to decode this float format to "normal" date time :-)

Could someone explain or give me a link when this is described? Any help will be very appreciated

Thanks in advance. Andriy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date/time format you have is the one Excel uses on Windows. If assign a number format to a date cell in Excel, you'll see the same numbers. You can also put the number into an Excel cell and assign it a date format to reveal the date.

It's basically the number of days since the 1st January, 1900 except that Excel has some mistakes regarding it's leap year handling.

You can turn it into a proper date using the following SQL expression:

```
select to_date('12/30/1899', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 40676.2641666667 from dual;
```

The number 40610.389837963 is converted to 3/8/2011 09:21 however. But I guess you mixed that up somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Codo for your answer. This is exactly what I needed.